# Adding classes to multiple divs using content within them

Tags: jquery

I'm dealing with some interesting html here. Html that I wish I could change, but I cannot unfortunately.

I have several random divs on the page that I need to be able to style. So I need to add classes to them to be able to call them out with css. This would normally not be a problem except the only unique thing about them is a word in the content.

The html looks like this

```
<div id="qualities">Top content</div>
<div>Becky something</div>
<div>Becky something else</div>
<div>Becky something different</div>
<div>Other content that I don't want to select</div>
<div>More content I don't want to select</div>
```

So I would like to select all the divs (so I can add a class) that have the word 'Becky' in them, but no other divs.

I don't want to look at any other elements higher up on the page. Is there a way that I can select these divs? This page is dynamic so there could be two, three, four of these so I'm trying to avoid `next()` or anything non-specific.

I've grabbed my venerable, which is Becky.

```
var catName = $('.pageCenterTitle').text()
catName = catName.replace(/(\w+).*/,"$1");
```

and have been trying different variations of 'contains', but have been failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to solve this can be based on element interation:

```
$('#qualities').nextAll('div')
```

Get all divs after the **#qualities**.

```js
$('#qualities').nextAll('div').each(function(idx, ele) {
    if (ele.textContent.indexOf('Becky') != -1) {
        ele.classList.add('redClass')
    }
})
```

```css
.redClass {
      background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="qualities">Top content</div>
<div>Becky something</div>
<div>Becky something else</div>
<div>Becky something different</div>
<div>Other content that I don't want to select</div>
<div>More content I don't want to select</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why my brain didn't want to think of this!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:contains` selector and select everything with "Becky" etc
To select all matching elements next to, and after a given element, you'd use `nextAll`

```js
$('#qualities').nextAll('div:contains("Becky")').addClass('becky')
```

```css
.becky {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Becky something else</div>
<div id="qualities">Top content</div>
<div>Becky something</div>
<div>Becky something else</div>
<div>Becky something different</div>
<div>Other content that I don't want to select</div>
<div>More content I don't want to select</div>
```

Comment: Ideally yes, but this would select other elements higher up on the page. I would like to try and only select those below the qualities div.

Comment: I heard that `:contains()` is depreciated?